# How can I use php to go through this json and add the items inside it to a mysqli database?

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am trying to allow an android user to replace a database table. My app reads in a excel spreadsheet from the phone, adds each row into a json, and then serializes the json to get a string:

```
[{"name":"catheter","alts":"cathater, cathiter, cath","num":"134"}, 
{"name":"cast","alts":"","num":"2212"}]
```

My app then sends the serializes json to a php file on my server where I

```
var_dump(json_decode($serializedString));
```

to get to the array in question:

```
array(2) {  [0]=>  object(stdClass)#2 (4) {    ["name"]=>    string(8) 
"catheter"    ["alts"]=>    string(24) "cathater, cathiter, cath"    
["num"]=>    string(3) "134"    }  [1]=>  object(stdClass)#3 (4) {    
["name"]=>    string(4) "cast"    ["alts"]=>    string(0) ""    
["number"]=>    string(0) ""    }}
```

I'm php stupid, but I have tried a BUNCH of stuff. This will tell me how many items there are in the array:

```
$count = 0;
$something = json_decode($serializedJsonString, true);
foreach($something as $obj){
    $count = $count+1;
}
echo $count;
```

I really need to be able to refer to each items key-value pairs so I can add them to a database which has columns for name, alt_names, and number. Thanks a bundle.

Comment: What exactly do you want doing? Do you just want to parse the JSON? It's doesn't seem clear from your question.

Comment: whish column you want to sum ?

Comment: I want to go through it with a for loop and stick each item in a mysqli database

Comment: show the table structure you want t save inside this data ?

Comment: i mean the name of your table

Comment: Maybe my question was too convoluted... I want to              INSERT INTO `my_table` (`name`, `alt_names`, `number`) VALUES ('sutures', 'stitches, seutures', '3453234'); for each element in the json

Comment: `$obj["name"]` would get you the name property within your foreach loop, for instance. So then you can use that as a parameter in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this can help you :

```
$serializedString= '[{"name":"catheter","alts":"cathater, cathiter, cath","num":"134"}, 
{"name":"cast","alts":"","num":"2212"}]';

$res = json_decode($serializedString, true);
```

function for isert data *(call it while looping the array)*

```
function insert($element , $mysqli){
    if(isset($element['name']) && isset($element['alts']) && isset($element['num'])){
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (name, alt_names,number ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
     $stmt->bind_param($element['name'], $element['alts'],$element['num']);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
   }

}
```

your main script :

```
$host = 'insert here the host';
$db = 'name of your database';
$username= 'db username';
$password = 'password db';


 // create database connection
 $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);
 $mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
 $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); // manage transaction

foreach($res as $key => $value){
   insert($value,$mysqli);
}
$mysqli->commit();
```

Comment: This goes in the right general direction, but downvoted for advocating a solution which is vulnerable to SQL injection, and uses a different library to the one the OP said they want to use...

Comment: Also consider that this could be made into a single SQL insert statement which would be more efficient...

Comment: @ADyson , using prepared statement avoid slq injection , i already update my answer. thank you

Comment: Thanks but you're still using PDO when the question clearly states they want to use mysqli

Comment: Better...but `catch (PDOException $e)` ??

Comment: Agreed. Enough for an upvote. N.B. A perfect solution would either turn this into a single SQL statement (more efficient), or at least wrap it all inside a transaction to ensure integrity. And ideally it would still handle exceptions (just not PDO exceptions). But thanks for tidying it up. It should demonstrate the concept nicely to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 0;
$something = json_decode($serializedJsonString, true);
foreach($arr as $item){
    $name = $item["name"];
    $alts = $item["alts"];
    $num = $item["num"];
//make insert query here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$db = new MySQLi(HOST, USER, PASS, SCHEMA, PORT);

$count = 0;
$elems = json_decode($serializedJsonString, true);

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO items (name, alt_names, number) VALUES (?,?,?)');

$db->begin_transaction();
foreach($elems as $elem){
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $elem['name'], $elem['alts'], $elem['num']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $count+1;
}

$stmt->close();
$db->commit();
$db->close();
echo $count;
```

This is also safe against any [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). And I've supposed that location and id are nullable and not available at the moment of this operation.

Comment: The only problem with this now is you're not reading the JSON structure correctly. $elems will be an array of objects - look at the sample data in the question. You need to loop that and construct an INSERT statement for each object. I wonder if you intended the prepare() and bind_param() to be inside your foreach loop?

Comment: Yeah, but with prepared statements it's not that easy. Performances could be improved with a transaction (since writes would be performed all on commit) or without using prepared statements and cleaning the inputs with `real_escape_string`.

Comment: what's not that easy?? I don't get your point. This code will not work, that's what I was saying. The bind_param() call will fail since $elem does not exist at that time. I think you made a mistake putting that outside your loop. I wasn't talking about transactions or performance. Although I agree, it would be better for integrity if all the statements were wrapped in a transaction, or if you made the code generate one single big INSERT statement to insert all the rows at once.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that. Also, speaking of copy-paste of code that won't work, I wasn't sure about prepared statement and checked out [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) link about that and I made that mistake watching that piece of code.

Comment: w3schools is notorious for inaccurate/ out of date tutorials etc, unfortunately. I rarely use it. Better to rely on the PHP documentation pages. Anyway thanks for updating, have an upvote